# react-medium-image-zoom unzoom on mobile back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, zooming, react-medium-image-zoom

I am developing a website using React. The website has many images that I use [react-medium-image-zoom](https://github.com/rpearce/react-medium-image-zoom) to make it zoomable. This is how I am using it.

```
<Zoom>
    <Image 
        className="zoom-image" 
        src={`images/exampleImage.jpg`} 
        onError={({ currentTarget }) => {
            currentTarget.onerror = null; // prevents looping
            currentTarget.src=`images/default.jpg`;
        }}
        loading="lazy"/>
</Zoom>
```

The problem is when mobile user, especially Android users, presses hardware back button on the mobile while the image is zoomed, the page gets back to the previous history stack, which I do not prefer. I want it to unzoom on pressing hardware back button on mobile. Is there a solution for this?

I already read the [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-medium-image-zoom) but I still do not understand how to tinker it for such behavior.